# Check if value in a Sass Map exists

Tags: css, sass

In the following SASS-code snippet I want to check if a map has a specific key. If not, it returns a default value (in this case `#bbb`)

```
@function contains($list, $var) {
    @return (false == index($list, $var));
}

$colors: (aaa: #aaa, bbb: #bbb);

$out: if(contains($colors, aaa), map-get($colors, aaa), #bbb);

body {
   color: $out;
}
```

For some reason it always returns `#bbb`. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you considered using a task manager like Grunt to add preprocess compiling to do just that?

Comment: I'm creating css-themes and I need to overwrite defaults. And a theme doesn't always overwrite a specific value, that why I need to check

Comment: Then no, SASS requires compiling - so there is no way to make JS see your SASS in a deploy environment. This would have to be done in preprocessing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first issue is that the return value is `null` if the value isn't found:

```
@function contains($list, $var) {
    @return (null == index($list, $var));
}
```

The second issue relates to the semantics of your contains function. Usually a function called *contains* should return true if the value was found in the list and false otherwise (at least I would expect that):

```
@function contains($list, $var) {
    @return (null != index($list, $var));
}
```

Then there is a third issue with calling the [index function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#index-instance_method) on a map. You would have to pass a key-value pair not just the key to this function:

```
$out: if(contains($colors, aaa #aaa), map-get($colors, aaa), #bbb);
```

Now it works as expected but for the sake of completeness let me tell you that there is already a built-in function which does exactly what you try to achieve with your `contains`-function; the [map_has_key($map, $key)](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_has_key-instance_method):

```
$out: if(map-has-key($colors, aaa), map-get($colors, aaa), #bbb);
```

Comment: TL;DR: `map-has-key($colors, aaa)`